# How to query a row

Tags: mysql

I have the following table (orders)

| orderID | customerID (varchar) | articleIDs (varchar) | date (datetime) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 | 9012, 9011, 9013 | 2023-09-19T01:15 |
| 2 | c1 | 9013 | 2023-08-12T09:35 |
| 3 | c2 | 9052, 9053, 9054 | 2023-09-17T11:16 |
| 4 | c3 | 9011, 9063 | 2023-09-12T03:24 |
| 5 | c4 | 9011, 9033 | 2023-09-09T09:09 |
| 6 | c4 | 9099, 9121, 9356 | 2023-09-17T08:55 |
| 7 | c2 | 9012, 9011 | 2023-08-19T07:11 |
| 8 | c5 | 9056, 9001, 9078 | 2023-09-19T06:25 |

Now I am trying to formulate a query that will answer the following: Which customer bought item x the last time?
For example, I want to know this for articleId 9011, my expectation is that I will get `c1 2023-09-19T01:15` back.

```
select customerID, max(orderdate) as d
from orders
where articleIDs like '%9011%'
group by customerID
order by d desc
limit 1;
```

This query is doing what I want. But is there any other/better solution?

Comment: Does each article in CSV list is 4-digit number strictly? Does this CSV value really contains parasite spaces after commas? Why you do not use normalized structure (or JSON array at least) instead? PS. DATETIME in MySQL cannot store shown values - the char `'T'` between date and time parts is obviously incorrect.

Comment: As far as I can see, the numbers always have 4 digits and yes there always seems to be a space as well. Unfortunately I can't change that anymore. It was not my decision to save it that way. this `T` seems to be some char added by the sql client I used. It is not in the DB

Comment: Test `.. WHERE 9011 MEMBER OF (CONCAT('[', articleIDs, ']')) ..`

Comment: It would be better to normalise your data during import, separating `orders` and `articles`.  With a row per `article` you can index the field to speed up your query.

Comment: Your solution will be broken if there is an articleId which is 90111 or something else that contains '9011'.

Comment: This is not how you'd structure this. Say you have products(prod_id, name, price...) and orders (order_id, customer_id, date). If you want to add multiple products to an order, you create a table order_products(product_id, order_id, quantity)

Comment: thanks @Akina. `WHERE 9011 MEMBER OF...` works. And this will also avoid the problem mentioned by @Hi-computer

Comment: .. but you must understand that any query will use full table scan on this structure - i.e. it will be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. Yes the structure is not optimal. But unfortunately I can not change that now in the short term. But definitely something I need to tackle soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FIND_IN_SET` function to search for values in a comma-separated string.

```
    SELECT customerID, MAX(orderdate) AS last_purchase_date
      FROM orders
     WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9011', REPLACE(articleIDs, ' ', '')) > 0
  GROUP BY customerID
  ORDER BY last_purchase_date DESC
     LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this:

```
SELECT customerID, MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM Orders
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('9011', REPLACE(articalIds, ' ', '')) > 0
GROUP BY customerID
ORDER BY max_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
select DISTINCT customerID, orderdate
from orders
where articleIDs like '%9011%'
order by d desc
limit 1;
```